# How to collate two time series dataframes that do not have matching times and contain different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, time-series, mismatch

I have two dataframes

```
df1 <- setNames(data.frame(c(as.POSIXct("2022-07-29 00:00:00","2022-07-29 00:05:00","2022-07-29 00:10:00","2022-07-29 00:15:00","2022-07-29 00:20:00")), c(1,2,3,4,5)), c("timeStamp", "value"))
df2 <- setNames(data.frame(c(as.POSIXct("2022-07-29 00:00:05","2022-07-29 00:05:05","2022-07-29 00:20:05")), c("a","b","c")), c("timeStamp", "text"))
```

I want to merge them into a single data frame by timeStamp, where the times are matched in chronological order, and the mismatching columns are simply filled in with NA. So it would read

```
timestamp              value     text
"2022-07-29 00:00:00"  1         NA
"2022-07-29 00:00:05"  NA        a
...
```

I can't for my life figure out why simply merge(x,y,by=) doesn't work for this. neither does left_join. It seems so simple and I can't seem to figure it out.

Also, a bonus would be to make it work this way as well, in which each time there is a change in text, all the rows below it remain the last text until the text changes again prompted by df2:

```
timestamp              value     text
"2022-07-29 00:00:00"  1         NA
"2022-07-29 00:00:05"  NA        a
"2022-07-29 00:05:00"  2         a
"2022-07-29 00:05:05"  NA        b
"2022-07-29 00:10:00"  3         b
"2022-07-29 00:15:00"  4         b
"2022-07-29 00:20:00"  5         b
"2022-07-29 00:20:05"  NA        c
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a full join.

tidyverse solution:

```
df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, c("timeStamp" = "timeStamp")) %>% 
  arrange(timeStamp) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(text)

            timeStamp value text
1 2022-07-29 00:00:00     1 <NA>
2 2022-07-29 00:00:05    NA    a
3 2022-07-29 00:05:00     2    a
4 2022-07-29 00:05:05    NA    b
5 2022-07-29 00:10:00     3    b
6 2022-07-29 00:15:00     4    b
7 2022-07-29 00:20:00     5    b
8 2022-07-29 00:20:05    NA    c
```

Base R merge:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c("timeStamp" = "timeStamp"), all = T)
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what in the simplest way. Side question: tidr::fill('variable') will always fill a new column with the previous value until the next one comes in?

Answer (score 0):

Using the corrected definitions of df1 and df2 in the Note at the end perform a `merge` using `all = TRUE` and then use `na.locf0` to fill in the NA's.

```
library(zoo)

m <- merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE) |> transform(text = na.locf0(text)); m
##             timeStamp value text
## 1 2022-07-29 00:00:00     1 <NA>
## 2 2022-07-29 00:00:05    NA    a
## 3 2022-07-29 00:05:00     2    a
## 4 2022-07-29 00:05:05    NA    b
## 5 2022-07-29 00:10:00     3    b
## 6 2022-07-29 00:15:00     4    b
## 7 2022-07-29 00:20:00     5    b
## 8 2022-07-29 00:20:05    NA    c
```

If the different values of text actually refer to different series that should be put in separate columns then we can create the following zoo series.  (Use `fortify.zoo(z)` if you need to convert that to a data frame.)

```
z <- read.zoo(m, split = "text"); z
##                      a  b  c
## 2022-07-29 00:00:05 NA NA NA
## 2022-07-29 00:05:00  2 NA NA
## 2022-07-29 00:05:05 NA NA NA
## 2022-07-29 00:10:00 NA  3 NA
## 2022-07-29 00:15:00 NA  4 NA
## 2022-07-29 00:20:00 NA  5 NA
## 2022-07-29 00:20:05 NA NA NA
```

### Note

```
df1 <- data.frame(timeStamp = as.POSIXct(c("2022-07-29 00:00:00",
"2022-07-29 00:05:00", "2022-07-29 00:10:00","2022-07-29 00:15:00",
"2022-07-29 00:20:00")), value = c(1,2,3,4,5))

df2 <- data.frame(timeStamp = as.POSIXct(c("2022-07-29 00:00:05",
"2022-07-29 00:05:05", "2022-07-29 00:20:05")), 
text = c("a","b","c"))
```